# fatal error define in PHP

Tags: php

I have some big problems with path to my php files. I got a suggestion that I should define my path for the root. But is this define correct, or do I need something else on it?

```
<?php
   // define path to application root 
   define( 'APP_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__) );
   require_once( APP_ROOT . '/resources/includes/header.html' );
?>
```

Because I still get the same error:

> Warning: require(/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/website/resources/auth/resources/includes/header.html): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/website/resources/auth/profile.php on line 4
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/website/resources/auth/resources/includes/header.html' (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.2/lib/php') in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/website/resources/auth/profile.php on line 4

Updated:

[image: Folder structure]

Comment: Does the file `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/website/resources/auth/resources/includes/header.html` definitely exist?

Comment: What does that error tell you? It tells *me* that the file is not where it's trying to load from.  It also tells me that it's looking here: `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/website/resources/auth/resources/includes/header.html` - **is that the right location**?

Comment: what the error tells me, is that APP_ROOT is not defined as you want it, because you want it to point to `'...htdocs/website/'`, but it includes the directory of the file in which you are defining it (`+recources/auth`). So make it `require_once( APP_ROOT . '../../resources/includes/header.html')`, or better: define APP_ROOT to what you want it!

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I just updated with a picture. It is 100% the correct path, as I see it? The correct location is `resources/includes/header.html`

Comment: Just tried to add: `define( 'APP_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__) );
require_once( APP_ROOT . '../../resources/includes/header.html')` , but still same error :-/

Comment: better try to set APP_ROOT to what you actually want it, either manually ( `define('APP_ROOT', '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/website/')` ) or by stripping the unwanted parts of `dirname(FILE)` (via substr() f.e.)

Comment: If I use this: `require_once( APP_ROOT . '../../includes/header.html')` my page is called, but not all my CSS in my headers. If I change those external CSS path, all my other sites are not working, because I change the path.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Ryan. I think it is because I am not quite understanding it. But I have tried to read something about it. As I understand it, My APP_ROOT folder is now website/ because my main files are here(picture from my question), that means the public files, when I person is going to my website. The path there should be included is resources/includes/header.html. That means I think the code should be: `require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/resources/includes/header.php');`

Comment: But the files I am working with now is named profile.php. That file lays under: 
`website/resources/auth/profile.php` and I would like to include my header which is laying in: `website/resources/includes/header.html`. That means my ROOT (/website)is 3 steps back from profil.